# Attach callback to Counter() value

Tags: python, callback, onchange

All the code provided is in python 3.3.

Let us assume I have created the following Counter() object:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> g = Counter(a=2, b=5, c=6, d = 3)
>>> g
Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 5, 'd': 3, 'c': 6})
```

I can now change all values in the Counter by simply executing something like

```
>>> g['b']=4
```

However, **I would like to detect when a specific value from the Counter is changed**. When this happens, I want a function to be executed which then increments another specific value from the Counter (If it's possible to do this directly, without a function - let me know).
For example, if 'a' is incremented, 'c' and 'd' should be, too.

CONTEXT:
I'm writing an algorithm that searches a string for substrings that have certain properties, writes those substrings into a list and then searches the substring for even tinier substring, assigning them to the higher substring. When the final function then counts all occurences of these substrings, I don't want it go through every hierarchy of the substrings, but rather just have to increment the higher substring. the attached callbacks should then increment all subsubstrings.
As I cannot add all callbacks all at once, **it would be great to have some method to add callbacks to the value on the run**.

Comment: You would need to subclass Counter, override `__setitem__`, and do your check there.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Read the Context, please. I assume that c and d are substrings of a. Maybe I should have stated that a bit more clearly.

Comment: @BrenBarn That is a good solution, unfortunately, I need to do this in a rather small script, as I will have to add the entire source code to a document which has a page limit. I simply cannot afford to subclass Counter(). Nonetheless, great approach. If everything else fails, I'll do that and tell my boss I needed more space :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [creating a class that behaves like any variable but has callback on change/read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854003/creating-a-class-that-behaves-like-any-variable-but-has-callback-on-change-read)

Comment: @SmeltQuake: You'll have to.  You can see the documentation for Counter [right here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).  There's nothing in there about callbacks.  Counter doesn't support anything of that sort out of the box.  If you need special behavior when setting an object's item with `obj[item] = blah`, `__setitem__` is the place to do it.  (Of course, you could also write your own class to do this independent of Counter, but that wouldn't really be any less work.)

Comment: @BrenBarn Seems like it. Thank you very much. I'll stick with modifying the Counter() class. Still leaving the thread open, in case somebody somehow has another idea.

Comment: By the way, what sorts of operations do you need to detect?  Like, do you just want to override `myCounter['a'] = 1`, or do you also need to override stuff like `myCounter['a'] += 1`?

Comment: @BrenBarn Actually, only the += one.

Comment: I added an answer showing how you might do this.  Overriding `+=` is actually tricker than overriding `=`, because `+=` operates on the value inside the container, not the container itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, you'll need to override `__setitem__`, either in a new subclass of Counter that you create, or in a new from-scratch class that you create.

However, your comment indicates you really want to override `g['a'] += 1`, which is more problematic.  Unless the object `g['a']` (not `g`) defines its own `__iadd__` method (which integers don't), then `g['a'] += 1` is the same as `g['a'] = g['a'] + 1`.  This means that `g` never gets to see the 1 that was added; it only gets to see the new resulting value after 1 is added.  In other words, if `g['a']` is 2 and you do `g['a'] += 1`, `g` never sees a 1 at all; it only sees 3 (which is what you get *after* adding 1 to its current value).

If you want to use the "incremental" difference to do your handling, you'll have to backfigure it yourself.  Here's a simple example where setting a new value for a string key also changes the values for all its individual characters, incrementing them by the difference between the old and new values for the original key:

```
class MagicCounter(collections.Counter):
    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        # see how much is being "added"
        diff = val - self[key]
        super(MagicCounter, self).__setitem__(key, val)
        if len(key) > 1:
            for item in key:
                self[item] += diff
```

Then:

```
>>> c = MagicCounter()
>>> c['a'] = 1
>>> c['b'] = 1
>>> c['c'] = 1
>>> c
MagicCounter({'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 1})
>>> c['abc'] += 1
>>> c
MagicCounter({'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'b': 2, 'abc': 1})
```

Comment: Definitely very helpful. Actually had an unclean workaround in mind, but I think I'll be able to work with this. Thank you very much.